# What is the name of these matrices?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, vectors

Guys I am looking for a named matrix. In this [geogebra link](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/gssue6ms) if I let, for example,
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
or
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -5\\5 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
and play with $\theta$, the vectors $w$ and $v$ rotate together (the angle between them never changes). My professor said that these type of matrices has a special name but he didn't say its name. Can you tell me what is the specific name of these matrices?

Comment: Why delete and repost, rather than edit the now-deleted question?

Comment: why do you care too much about my question, but not what I want ?

Comment: Because all the effort put in by those who commented on your previous question was for naught. If you do **not** respect others' time, why should anyone invest any time answering your questions? You should rewrite and refine questions, not delete and repost.

Comment: There was nothing about the questionin the comments. Everybody was trying to judge like they have a right to do. That's why I deleted that post.

Comment: Your question needed **a lot** of improvement. You could have rewritten it, which would have made the comments obsolete. Then, you could have flagged the comments as "no longer needed". Comments are ephemeral. Once deleted, you no longer have to look at them, and only special people — moderators, I assume — can see them.

Answer (score 0):

These matrices
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}a&-b\\b&a\end{array}\right]$$
are related to a complex number $a+ib$.

In terms of algebraic structures both sets, of those kind of matrices and the complex numbers, are isomorphic fields.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean skew-symmetric matrices? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix?wprov=sfla1

Comment: I know what Skew symmetric matrix is and it satisfies the condition. However, I dont know what I am really looking for :)